# Issue with deleting sprites from a group in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a level creating platformer game that I have been making. In my update loop, if my selected block type is -1, and the mouse is down, then it iterates through a group containing sprites for my game.

In this iteration, I have some code that checks if our mouse is touching that sprite. If it is touching it, then the sprite is destroyed with the `destroy();` function. If I only have one sprite in the game, then it works fine, but otherwise it gives me the error `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'body')"`. I would like it to delete when my mouse touches it. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you would have to share code, since this sound like a problem with your code and not with phaser. if possible only the relevant parts of the `create` and `update` functions

Comment: coins.children.iterate(function(child) {
    if ( [mouse touching coin] ) {
        child.destroy();
    }
}); This is what it looks like. As far as I can tell, the loop stops working because its looping through something that no longer exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is, that the `update` function is call so fast, that the `destroy` function is called multiple times on the same `child`, before it is fully destroyed. You could just add an extra check in your `if`-clause, before you call the `destroy` function.

Something like this, should do the trick:

```
coins.children.iterate(function(child) { 
    if ( child && child.body && [mouse touching coin] ) { 
        child.destroy(); 
    } 
});
```