Phaser game freezing after 5 seconds: issue with primary platform disappearing or platform generation?
I'm developing a platform game using Phaser, and I've encountered a frustrating issue where the game freezes after approximately 5 seconds of gameplay. I suspect the problem may be related to either the primary platform disappearing or a glitch in the platform generation mechanism.
Below is the code for my game:
var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {
            gravity: { y: 300 },
            debug: false
        }
    },
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
var player;
var cursors;
var platforms;
var obstacles;
var jumpCount = 0;
var maxJumps = 2;
var gapWidth = 400; // Initial gap width between platforms
var score = 0;
var scoreText;
function preload() {
    this.load.image('background', 'assets/images/realistic-spring-landscape_23-2148852143.avif');
    this.load.image('player', 'assets/do-your-cat-in-pixel-art.jpg');
    this.load.image('obstacle', 'assets/images/enemy.png');
    this.load.image('platform', createSolidColorTexture('yellow', 800, 20));
}

function create() {
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'background');

    // Create the player
    player = this.physics.add.sprite(200, 491, 'player');
    player.setOrigin(0.5, 0.5); // Set origin to the center of the image
    player.setCollideWorldBounds(true);
    player.setScale(0.1);
    player.setBounce(0.2);
    player.setGravityY(300);

    cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    // Create the platforms group
    platforms = this.physics.add.group({
        allowGravity: false,
        immovable: true
    });

    // Create the obstacles group
    obstacles = this.physics.add.group({
        allowGravity: false,
        immovable: true
    });

    // Create a long initial platform
    var initialPlatform = platforms.create(400, 550, 'platform');
    initialPlatform.displayWidth = 1600; // Make it long enough for about 4 seconds
    initialPlatform.setVelocityX(-200);

    // Collision handlers
    this.physics.add.collider(player, platforms, function () {
        jumpCount = 0;
    });

    // Initialize score text
    scoreText = this.add.text(16, 16, 'Score: 0', { fontSize: '32px', fill: '#FFF' });

    // Timer for obstacle and platform generation
    this.time.addEvent({
        delay: 1500, // Decreased delay to spawn more frequently
        callback: generateObstaclesAndPlatforms,
        callbackScope: this,
        loop: true
    });
}
var lastPlatformX = 800; // Variable to track the x-coordinate of the last generated platform

function update() {
    player.setVelocityX(0); // Reset horizontal velocity

    if (cursors.left.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(-160);
    } else if (cursors.right.isDown) {
        player.setVelocityX(160);
    }

    if (cursors.up.isDown && (player.body.touching.down || jumpCount < maxJumps)) {
        player.setVelocityY(-400);
        jumpCount++;
    }

    // Destroy off-screen platforms
    platforms.children.iterate(function (child) {
        if (child.x < -child.displayWidth / 2) {
            child.destroy(); // Remove platforms that are off-screen
        }
    });

    // Destroy off-screen obstacles
    obstacles.children.iterate(function (child) {
        if (child.x < -child.width) {
            child.destroy(); // Remove obstacles that are off-screen
        }
    });

    // Generate new platforms if needed
    if (lastPlatformX < 800) {
        generateObstaclesAndPlatforms();
    }

    // Increment score based on time alive
    score += 1;
    scoreText.setText('Score: ' + score);
}

function generateObstaclesAndPlatforms() {
    var platformGap = Phaser.Math.Between(gapWidth, gapWidth + 200); // Generate a random gap width
    var platformWidth = (800 - platformGap) / 2; // Calculate platform width to keep the gap centered

    var platform1 = platforms.create(lastPlatformX + platformGap, 550, 'platform');
    platform1.displayWidth = platformWidth;
    platform1.setVelocityX(-200);
    platform1.setImmovable(true);

    var platform2 = platforms.create(lastPlatformX + platformGap + platformWidth, 550, 'platform');
    platform2.displayWidth = platformWidth;
    platform2.setVelocityX(-200);
    platform2.setImmovable(true);

    lastPlatformX += platformGap + platformWidth; // Update the last platform x-coordinate
}


function createSolidColorTexture(color, width, height) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    return canvas.toDataURL();
}


In this game, players control a character navigating platforms. The primary platform, which spans the width of the screen, disappears after a few seconds, leading to the game freeze. Additionally, I've noticed that the platform generation function may not be working as intended.
I've tried debugging the code and tweaking various parameters, but I haven't been able to pinpoint the exact cause of the freeze. Any insights, suggestions, or alternative approaches to platform generation would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!
I've tried adjusting the platform generation logic by refining the generation process to ensure a continuous stream of platforms. I expected the game to run smoothly without freezing, with platforms consistently generated and removed as needed. However, despite these adjustments, the game still freezes after approximately 5 seconds of gameplay.

Seems to be the same issue like in this question & answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/73589799/1679286 If I'm mistaken please et me know.

Is you Question solved or do you still need some more help?

Basically you need to check if the child and the physics-body still exists, since it could be partial delete, when the update function is called the next time. Which would cause the Error.
That you mean for your update function to add some checks (as mentioned in this answer):
(I remove irrelevant code for the sake of brevity)
function update() {
    // some code...

    platforms.children.iterate(function (child) {
        // skip the destroy call if object is already destroyed
        if (child && child.body && child.x < -child.displayWidth / 2) {
            child.destroy(); // Remove platforms that are off-screen
        }
    });

    // Destroy off-screen obstacles
    obstacles.children.iterate(function (child) {
        // skip the destroy call if object is already destroyed
        if (child && child.body &&child.x < -child.width) {
            child.destroy(); // Remove obstacles that are off-screen
        }
    });

    // some more code ...
}


Just for completeness: with the checks child && child.body we are checking if child != null and child.body != null, before accessing the properties or calling methods on those objects.

